# Converting iphone app to universal woes?

Tags: iphone, ipad, nib, universal

I've converted my app to a universal app in xCode 4. This created me my MainWindow-iPad.xib automatically and modified my info.plist to include the iPad version of my Main Nib File Base Name....(MainWindow-iPad).

Sadly though, my app appears to be still using my iphone version of my MainWindow.xib.

This can't be right.  My target is set to Universal.

Can anyone suggest why my iPad version isn't being used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it!

I needed to do a ios reset on the ipad simulator. Just stumbled upon it

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Project and Find your plist

Right click in the plist and select "Show raw keys/value pairs"

You should see two ipad entries

```
NSMainNibFile~ipad

and 

UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad
```

NSMainNibFile~ipad should have the name of your ipad interface.

inside UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad
you should have at least one key.
My app is Landscape so here are the ones I have

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

Sometimes the project editor does not edit the Plist correctly.

verify these settings and verify the class types and connections in the ipad xib file are correct.

Hope that helps.